# Установить редактор по умолчанию Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Устанавливаю редактор по умолчанию командой

```
export EDITOR=mcedit
```

После рестарта сессии это приходится проделывать повторно.
Как запомнить эту настройку?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```bsh
update-alternatives --config editor
```

или к примеру для установки `mcedit` по умолчанию:

```bsh
update-alternatives --set editor /usr/bin/mcedit
```

Ну или (на правах костыля) можно Вашу `export EDITOR=mcedit` забить в `~/.bashrc`